# find 3 words A B C such that both A B C and B C A make sense

Tags: wordplay

When I take the three words "boy", "meets" and "girl", the sentence "boy meets girl" is correct, but "meets girl boy" is not.

**Could you think of three distinct words for which both expressions are correct and make sense?**

Note to the downvoters: sorry if this question bothers you. This is my first one of the site. I first posted it on english.stack-exchange, but someone said it would be a better fit here. I agree that there is certainly many correct answers. I just would like one to illustrate a basic programming exercise (i.e., "rotating" the value of 3 variables).

Comment: I take it the words must be distinct, or else there are various trivial examples, such as "Buffalo buffalo buffalo".

Comment: Yes. I edit my question.

Comment: Are words that form a question allowed?

Comment: affirmation -> question are lots of possibilities.

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer not to need any punctuation.

Comment: Downvoted since this is subjective and too broad. Puzzles should have one objectively correct answer.

Comment: Could be made [`open-ended`](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-ended) by changing the challenge to find the longest pair of sentences `A B C D ... W` and `B C D ... W A`

Comment: @humn Good idea, but in my opinion your exact suggestion would make the challenge easier (cf. Beastly Gerbil general answers). I think one could make the challenge harder in two distinct ways. 1. find the "De Bruijn sentence" of maximal length (ex. ABC, BCA, CAB would be valid sentences of length 3). 2. find two sentences ABC and BCA where each A, B, C have different meaning / grammatical function in their sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple solution is to write

> ADVERB, PRONOUN, VERB and then make it PRONOUN, VERB, ADVERB

For instance

> **Sometimes people think** and **People think sometimes**

And

> **Slowly I drive** and **I drive slowly**

Another example

> **Daily they read** and **They read daily**

Another solution found by Jonathan Allan is

> PRONOUN, PRONOUN, VERB and PRONOUN, VERB, PRONOUN

For instance

> **Anyone you know** and **You know anyone**

And

> **Somebody we saw** and **We saw someone**

Once again

> **Others he met** and **He met others**

There can be words with multiple meanings which will work:

> **On right side** (on the right hand side) and **Right side on** (the correct side is on)

Comment: @Aristide fixed with some correct example

Comment: Thanks, it's indeed correct now. Sorry if I wait for some more "interesting" examples (see the added "motivation" part in my post).

Comment: @Aristide I'll try and find other methods beside Adverb, pronoun, verb

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Yes, these are good "general" examples. I'll certainly go with Jonathan Allan's one. But I guess there exist some more playful, non general examples, in which changing the position of the words changes their meaning too...

Comment: @Aristide I actually am looking at multi-defined words write now to see if I can find one like that

Comment: @Aristide found one, will try and add more

Answer (score 3):

Aww sweet:

> Someone I love; I love someone

Answer (score 2):

A B C:

> Half a cookie

B C A:

> A cookie half

Comment: 'A cookie half?' don't think that works

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an english native speaker. What means "A cookie half"?

Comment: @Aristide it doesn't mean anything, it is not a valid sentence

Comment: I'm interpreting it with "half" as the noun and "cookie" describing that noun. :P

Comment: The second is not something I'd expect to be used regularly but I'd agree with @jstnthms that using half as a noun and cookie to describe that half is valid.